# Types of Excercises with my Particular Excercise Band

Tags: exercise, resistance-cord

[40 in Resistance Band](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Athletic-Works-Resistance-Bands-Heavy-Natural-Latex-40inx1-26in-Dark-Gray/348267998)

I have the preceding resistance band I was wondering what type of exercises I can do with it. So far I have been doing overhead resistance pull apart, and a biceps curl for resistance bands. Any thoughts on what exercises I can add to increase my exercise portfolio? By the way, I am 5 feet 11 inches, or 6 feet tall, so probably this resistance is not the right one... However, I would still be open to your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, you can probably add it onto anything:

- [Banded deadlifts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obM6SBVa-MU)
- [Banded squats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJQHqSJ6xFo) and [different versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CbPyDr2P0w)
- [Banded push-ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOFwFzzLFWw)
- [Band-assisted pull-ups/chin-ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ_O6Ma3RvA)
- [Banded rows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtLxvPDGYlE) or [seated rows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiP_S1jwHvE)
- [Banded face-pulls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jgKj8ColLg)
- [Banded bicep curls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZhnV2UX_EQ)
- [Banded tricep pull-downs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW8L2POShSA) or [extensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAZTvVj3YPk)

Basically, with a bit of imagination, and possibly a solid anchor point on a door or wall, you can hit every muscle group with resistance bands. Take any normal exercise you would do and just add "banded" to the front of it in a YouTube search.

I would strongly suggest to get a few different "levels" of resistance bands. The one you linked, for example, is that manufacturer's 4/5 difficulty; I would purchase the 2/5 and the 3/5 as well. Just like with weights, some exercises you'll want more resistance.

You can also manipulate the band as well for exercises to be harder or easier. For banded bicep curls, for example, you could place the band under both feet and hold it in both hands, or, under one foot and in just one hand, or doubled up under one foot and still in one hand. All of those will change the difficulty by changing at what point in the bands tension you're beginning the lift.